# Are there ascii characters that can not be sent across the internet?

Tags: networking, binary, ascii

I am building a web application that will send a set of flag states to its server by converting the flags into binary, then converting the binary into ascii characters.  The ascii characters will be sent using a post command, then a response (encoded the same way) will be sent back.  I would like to know if there are ascii character that can cause the HTTP requests and data transfer to break down or get misdirected.  Are there standard ascii characters (0-127) that need to be avoided?

Comment: This seems to be a lot of extra work. Is the web application an HTML page? Could it have a form with input elements? Or, why not use AJAX or other XHR? XHR and HTTP handle binary just fine.

Comment: There are 90 different states being tracked.  The data is then sent to an Arduino over a 32 character buffer.

Comment: So far, I have not run into any trouble with any of the 128 characters

Answer (score 0):

Despite its name, HTTP is agnostic to the format and semantics of the entity-body content. It doesn't need to be text. Describing it as text and giving a character encoding is metadata for the sending and receiving applications. Your actual entity-data isn't text but if you've added a layer of re-interpretation so you *could* provide that metadata.

HTTP bodies are of two types: counted or chunked. For counted, the message-body is the same as the entity-body. Counted is used unless you want to start streaming data before knowing its entire length. Just send the [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) header with the number of octets in the entity-body and copy it into the output stream.